# Assign "variable variables" to a directory

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, variable-assignment

I would like to assign the following variable names to a directory for easy manipulation later. The idea is as follow:

```
data_1= fits.getdata(.....)
data_2= fits.getdata(.....)
data_3= fits.getdata(.....)
```

.
.

```
N=10
d={}
for i in range(N):
  d['data_'+ str(i)] = data_i
```

Is there a way to call the variables in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a working solution (Please see my comments in the code for better understanding). But you have to pay attention to use the `eval` function in Python, [it's quite dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

**Code:**

```
data_1 = 1
data_2 = 2
data_3 = 3

N=10
d={}
for i in range(N):
    try:
        # IT DANGEROUS TO USE EVAL FUNCTION.
        d['data_{}'.format(i)] = eval('data_{}'.format(i))
    except NameError:
        # Cannot set the variable in the dict. Get next element of loop.
        pass

# Testing statements...
print(d["data_1"])
print(d["data_3"])
print(d["data_2"] + d["data_3"])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
1
3
5
```